# ValueError: Could not interpret value for parameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, relplot

load "bmi.csv" into the Dataframe and create a scatter plot of the data using
relplot() with height on x-axis and weight on y-axis and color the plot
points based on Gender and vary the size of the points by BMI index.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv('bmi.csv')

BMI = pd.DataFrame(df)
g = sns.relplot(x = 'Height', y = 'Weight', data=df);b
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    g = sns.relplot(x = 'Height', y = 'Weight', data=df);b
  File "/Users/aleksikurunsaari/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py", line 862, in relplot
    p = plotter(
  File "/Users/aleksikurunsaari/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py", line 538, in __init__
    super().__init__(data=data, variables=variables)
  File "/Users/aleksikurunsaari/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/seaborn/_oldcore.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.assign_variables(data, variables)
  File "/Users/aleksikurunsaari/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/seaborn/_oldcore.py", line 701, in assign_variables
    plot_data, variables = self._assign_variables_longform(
  File "/Users/aleksikurunsaari/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/seaborn/_oldcore.py", line 938, in _assign_variables_longform
    raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: Could not interpret value `Height` for parameter `x`
```

Comment: Please check `df.columns`.  Maybe there are extra spaces in the column names?

Comment: Where did you download the bmi.csv data? I would recommend to use [Kaggle - BMI data](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yasserh/bmidataset). Works easily without an issue on reproducing the above code implementation.

Comment: For others searching for this error, it can be also caused by having the df as first unnamed argument to the seaborn plotting function.

Comment: The error message returned by seaborn in this case is simply poor. Would be much more informative if it said something like "variable `Height` not found".

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue, and [Melkor.cz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531969/valueerror-could-not-interpret-value-for-parameter/77908048#comment135285368_74531969) was the reason:

> For others searching for this error, it can be also caused by having the df as first unnamed argument to the seaborn plotting function.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the error, why are you constructing a dataframe from a dataframe and also you're not using it ? I'm talking about `BMI` here :

```
df = pd.read_csv('bmi.csv')
BMI = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

And regarding the error, this one has occured because `Height` is not one of the columns of `df`. I suggest you to check the content/shape/columns of this dataframe before plotting with seaborn. It may be a problem with the separator of your `.csv`.

```
sns.relplot(x = 'Height', y = 'Weight', data=df)
```

[image]

*Dataset: https://github.com/aniketsoni1/BMI-Data-Insight-using-SVM/blob/master/bmi.csv*

Comment: Hi, I deleted BMI later because I didn't need it. But yeah there indeed was a problem with my .csv file. I changed the csv file and got it to work. Thank you very much!